# Center moving drawRect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect

In my app, a circle is drawn based on a users drag. e.g. a user taps, that is the center of a circle that will be drawn, and as they drag their finger, the circle will grow to that point. This works, except for some reason the center moves down and to the right as the radius of the circle grows. Why is this happening? Here is what I am trying:

```
@implementation CircleView{
    CGPoint center;
    CGPoint endPoint;
    CGFloat distance;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    center = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGFloat xDist = (endPoint.x - center.x);
    CGFloat yDist = (endPoint.y - center.y);
    distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x,center.y,distance, distance);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

What should be happening is that center point never ever moves, and the circle should just grow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x,center.y,distance, distance);
```

should be:

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x - distance, center.y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
```

Comment: Figured it out, it is actually center.x -(distance/2), just subtracting from distance inverses the center location, but yes. I'll accept your answer when I can!

Comment: I was assuming that `distance` was the radius of the circle.

Comment: It is! I don't actually know why it works, but it does. Both ways work, so i'll accept your answer and post both the solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Because in `CGRectMake` you have to specify the origin (and the size) of the rectangle, not the center.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x - distance, center.y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
```

Comment: The 2nd gives you a circle with half the size of the 1st. The 2nd gives you a circle that will be half the distance from the center to the user's finger.